# Android : Exif of a Byte[] or Bitmap object

Tags: android, caching, exif

Is it possible to read the Exif header of a Byte[] or Bitmap object without write it on the disk?
I only found one constructor [ExifInterface(String filename)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface%28java.lang.String%29), and it doesn't seem possible to do that. Could you please confirm?

Otherwise, how could I save that bitmap on the cache directory and take it back in order to read the Exif header?

Comment: On a scale of 1-10 for difficulty, decompressing a JPEG image is probably an 8 while parsing the EXIF info is closer to 2.  It's not hard to walk the JPEG marker list to find the APP1 containing the EXIF header and then process the fake TIFF file to look for the orientation tag.

Comment: If it is not hard to do then please show some code. @BitBank.

Answer (score 4):

You could use my [metadata-extractor](https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) library. It has classes that'll decode Exif (and other formats) from `byte[]`, streams, files...

Something like this should work:

```
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
new ImageMetadataReader().extract(new ByteArrayReader(bytes), metadata);
```

Now you can inspect the `Metadata` object.

The lib is available via Maven.

Comment: Your sample not worked for me, error "com.drew.imaging.tiff.TiffProcessingException: Unclear distinction between Motorola/Intel byte ordering: -40" occurred while reading jpg byte[] data. Then I changed to the following code and it works!! Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), data.length, FileType.Jpeg);

Comment: @fantouch thanks, you can use `ImageMetadataReader` if you have a complete image file's data. Use `ExifReader` if you have only the Exif segment for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The sample code of @Drew Noakes doesn't work for me, error occurred while reading jpg byte[] data:

```
GrallocMapperPassthrough: buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2080000
System.err: com.drew.imaging.tiff.TiffProcessingException: Unclear distinction between Motorola/Intel byte ordering: -40
System.err:     at com.drew.imaging.tiff.TiffReader.processTiff(TiffReader.java:60)
```

Then I changed to the following code and it works!!

```
try {
    Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), data.length, FileType.Jpeg);
    for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
        for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
            Log.d(TAG, tag.toString());
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you have a full image's data then use `ImageMetadataReader`. If you have somehow extracted the Exif data from somewhere then use `ExifReader`. I've updated my answer as it's more likely that users have the full image data.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap have no exif header. You can save the bitmap as .png but exif is not for .png. You can save the bitmap as a .jpg file. But it will have no exif info then. But you could add it with Exifinterface i hope.

A byte array if it contains a .jpg file with an exif header would be ok. But Exifinterface is not able to read that indeed.

Comment: Yes, it's a jpg file. I took a picture and saved it on the server. The problem is, that when It goes back, the picture's orientation has changed. This is why I need to read the Exif metadata in order to display it correctly.

Comment: did you ever figure this out Denis? I'm struggling with the same thing.

Comment: The exif orientation will not change if you upload a jpg file to a server. Or if you download one. You are doing something wrong in between.